# Run Multiple Jar files sequentially (not simultaneously) on "docker run imagename" command

Tags: java, shell, docker, ubuntu, jar

I have two jar files(a.jar and b.jar). b.jar have dependency on a.jar. b.jar can run only after a.jar is up and running. I want to run them via single docker run command. My docker file is like this

```
# base image is java:8 (ubuntu)
FROM java:8

# add files to image 
ADD a.jar .
ADD b.jar .
ADD start.sh .

# start on run
CMD ["bash", "start.sh"]
```

start.sh is like this ,

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar docker-spring-boot.jar &
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar docker-spring-boot-secondary.jar
```

When i am running docker image both jars are running simultaneously.

When my start.sh is like this,

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar docker-spring-boot.jar;
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar docker-spring-boot-secondary.jar;
```

Then only a.jar is running.

I took a help of this [How to have two JARs start automatically on "docker run container"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283916/how-to-have-two-jars-start-automatically-on-docker-run-container)

Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: After first command of the last snippet the script waits while the `java` process exits and only then will start the second `java`. If you want start the first jar, wait while it boots, then start the second jar, you need to use your second snippet (with `java -jar docker-spring-boot.jar &`), but insert a loop with a health check (e.g. using `curl`) between `java` launches.

Comment: @DanilaKiver can u please share the snippet of start.sh

Comment: I cannot because I don't know how exactly you should check whether the first JAR is "started enough" to proceed to the second one. It's up to you to develop this criterion and the means to check it (maybe a `/health` endpoint?).

Comment: How does the one application depend on the other (in a totally separate JVM)?  In particular, does it make sense to launch these as two separate containers?

Comment: @DavidMaze They will be running in single container , not in two seperate containers

Comment: Why?  Multiple processes in a single container usually isn't considered a best practice, if it's avoidable.

Comment: @DavidMaze We will create separate services for each functionality. So if i have 100 jars , i don't want to create docker image 100 times and  write docker run 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a script that checks if "a.jar is up and running" and insert it before the second jar call in the following way:

```
java -jar a.jar &
wait_till_a_jar_is_up_and_running && 
java -jar b.jar
```

Note: it is important that second time you use `&&` but not `&`.

None of us knows what "a.jar is up and running" as we don't know what a.jar does. You'll need to implement it yourself (most likely [wait-for-it.sh will help you](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)).

For testing purposes you can try using `sleep` command:

```
java -jar a.jar & sleep 10 && java -jar b.jar
```

Where `sleep 10` just waits 10 seconds before running the second jar.